# Changing Nvidia Driver black screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 15.04

I searched everyone online for solution, but it is still not working.

At first I changed the Nvidia driver to use the propriety driver from the additional tab, twice, and it shows black screen which cause me to reinstall.

And then I learnt about the alt+ctrl+f1 to show command prompt.

When I tested Dota 2 in Ubuntu with nouveau driver, there is some lagging. And when I tried it in my Linux Mint, it works smoothly. My mint is using propriety driver.

So I decided to try to change it again on my Ubuntu. And Voila! Blackscreen ?
Seriously such a popular distro can have so many bugs? For example like suspending and not waking up? I could just change the driver in Additional Driver tab in Mint without problem but not Ubuntu?

So I tried many times purging it, installing dkms, downloading drivers from Nvidia sites, all sort of method.
Sometimes it shows black screen, sometimes login loop, sometimes logged in but no Unity, but I can right click open terminal and use the terminal though.

Seriously anyone got a proper solution for this? I updated and installed everything in my Ubuntu properly already I do not hope for a need to reinstall.
Thanks.

I'm Using Ubuntu 15.04

Nvidia GeForce GTX 860X

Intel i7-4720HQ with graphical in it

prime-select query shows

```
nvidia
```

xorg.conf file is default, not changed when booted up.

Actually I did try to change back to nouveau but it does not load Unity, probably because I'm using Compiz? But now I'm trying to get Nvidia driver to work!

EDIT : Now my Nvidia version is 346, from default repository. Still black screen

EDIT: I successfully changed back to nouveau and enable Unity through CCSM. Nvidia drivers are not working at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Try to manually change the graphic driver using GUI (Nvidia Bee).

Comment: This answer is somewhat ambiguous. What GUI? Did you mean Settings > Additional Drivers (part of `software-properties-gtk`)? Better to mention that so other users can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Install the drivers by running in terminal or console

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

To get to console you can press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login there and run this command, then

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Oh, how I wish that would be functional for me. I usually get a black screen or a nonfunctional GUI login screen (typing not possible).

Comment: I added explanation how to run it.

Comment: Well, I have tried it both forwards and backwards - and only find it to be totally impossible to fault find.

Comment: It is not backwards or forwards. You need to press them simultaneously.

Comment: simply doing this would just get me a black screen.

Comment: "forwards and backwards" refers to a multitude of attempts to get the driver installed, in any conceivable way there is. Have a nice day.

Comment: That was a wrong idea to install a driver from a `run` file downloaded from Nvidia site. With your level of knowledge it will be much easier to re-install the system and install the driver the correct way.

Comment: But you can boot to recovery using grub menu or boot with `nomodeset` parameter.

Comment: @Pilot6 I can simply alt+ctrl+f1 and then play with the driver. The problem is no matter how it wouldn't work. There's a time I booted in but Unity failed to load.

Comment: Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and enable unity there.

Comment: Just tested your commands above to install nvidia, simple doesn't work. Getting a black screen

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Xorg are you using?
If it is >= 1.17.2 then you probably have the same problem I had with NVidia and PRIME.

Gigabyte Notebook with hybrid Intel + Nvidia GTX 765M card with PRIME not working with (K)Ubuntu 16.04 with any version of the proprietary NVIDIA driver. When prime-select switched to nvidia gives a black screen, set to intel worked. NVidia proprietary driver prime-select set to nvidia worked on (K)Ubuntu 14.04 before.

The solution that worked for me (with latest stable driver 367.57, from graphics ppa, but should work with every driver) was to change xorg.conf!

The version of Xorg shipped with (K)Ubuntu 16.04 is 1.18.4, where the BusID format in xorg.conf was slightly changed in Xorg >= 1.17.2.
I changed `BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"` on the nvidia card to `BusID "PCI:1::0:0"` and similar process on the intel section and also added the LoadModule setting. Like described in an answer to a post on askubuntu. see: https://askubuntu.com/a/776527

I guess the broken id works on PRIME set to intel because autodetection in single-intel mode is much better then the Nvidia PRIME stuff.

After restart it worked, but something changed my xorg.conf again to have invalid data. I'm now experimenting with deactivating gpu-manager by commenting all lines in /etc/init/gpu-manager.conf (see https://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/ ) and setting "chattr +i" for xorg.conf.

and see ArchWiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#Using_nvidia

Hope this solves your problems with NVidia PRIME too!