# Nvidia drivers and UEFI working together

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, uefi, secure-boot

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and after enabling Secure Boot Nvidia drivers stops loading. Same is with VirtualBox kernel modules. When I try to force loading kernel

```
# modprobe nvidia_361
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_361': Required key not available sign module
```

I read that from Ubuntu 16.04 version kernel prevents loading unsigned modules. Is there any way to turn on Secure Boot and use proprietary kernel modules, without compiling own kernel?

Comment: I will add answer for that because I have solution. I'm able to leave Secure Boot on and use proprietary kernel modules.

Comment: I cant add answer in this question so here is a link to my answer in other similar question.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/761886/ubuntu-16-04-kernel-4-4-0-21-not-loading-nvidia-vboxdrv-modules-anymore-require/773852#773852