# Unable to use nvidia gpu with optimus on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, gpu, nvidia-settings

I'm having a dell inspiron 7567 in which im not able to use the nvidia gpu (Geforce GTX 1050). At first i only installed the nvidia driver and tried signing the MOK by following the steps from 
https://gist.github.com/Garoe/74a0040f50ae7987885a0bebe5eda1aa
since i'm using UEFI and enabled secure boot.

When i used the command `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"`
i found that my laptop was still using the intel gpu even when gazebosim was running.

Then decided to use bumblebee and did all the steps as mentioned in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nGbWE-pvIE). After doing everything in the video i restarted my laptop and i found the indicator as the guy from the video got( it shows me the nvidia logo instead of the intel logo that the guy from the video got ) but was still not able to change to the nvidia gpu with it.

When i tried running `optirun glxgears` i get the following error

> [ 3411.396308] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
>
> [ 3411.396337] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

for `lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'` i get

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c8d] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

for `sudo inxi -G` i get

> Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 591b
>            Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1c8d
>           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
>            tty size: 80x24 Advanced Data: N/A for root

in my bumblebee.conf file i changed `Driver=` to `Driver=nvidia`, `Bridge=auto` to `Bridge=primus`,replaced `nvidia-current` with `nvidia-378`(which is the nvidia driver im using), changed `PMMethod=auto` to `PMMethod=bbswitch` the rest of the file is left as default

for `sudo lshw -numeric -C display` i get

> *-display UNCLAIMED
>         description: VGA compatible controller
>          product: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE:1C8D]
>          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>          version: a1
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
>          configuration: latency=0
>          resources: memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
>     *-display
>          description: VGA compatible controller
>          product: Intel Corporation [8086:591B]
>          vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
>          physical id: 2
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>          version: 04
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>          configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>          resources: irq:126 memory:d4000000-d4ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

my nvidia x server settings dont have many tabs. It only shows me application profiles tab and nvidia settings configuration when its supposed to have many more tabs.

i read a lot about this issue on different forums but i still could'nt get it to work. So could somebody please give me a fix for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you like complicating so much just for installing a driver you should go to arch-linux, since 2013 ubuntu worked well on nvidia drivers  for making it easy to install, so type these commands in order `sudo apt install intel-microcode` and `sudo apt install nvidia-xxx` I put `xxx` because you must use the ubuntu recommended driver for your system, and you will know that using `ubuntu-drivers devices` command this will display the correct nvidia version for your computer, please see this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/931633/how-to-install-my-nvidia-driver/931641#931641

Comment: i had already done all that but it still didn't work because i tried doing it with secure boot on. This time i redid the whole process after purging all that i had done before and didn't try making it work with secure boot on and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Bumblebee does not work well on Ubuntu 16. You should use prime.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-378 nvidia-prime
```

Prior to doing this you should purge bumbleebe and whatever else you installed.

Comment: prime comes with the `nvidia-xxx` package so adding next to it is redundant

Comment: @ previous comment, It doesn't come with it, it recommends it.

Comment: thank you do much!!!! it works!! i used nvidia-381 instead of nvidia-378. Is there a way to use the nvidia driver along with secure boot on ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/761886/ubuntu-16-04-kernel-4-4-0-21-not-loading-nvidia-vboxdrv-modules-anymore-require/773852#773852