# Ubuntu is showing me update packages that I don't need, How can I delete them?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

In Ubuntu 14.04.5 I did `sudo apt-get upgrade` intencionally for holding kernel updates and I installed `nvidia-375` because I have a GTX 740M I know that if I update the kernel, my GPU driver will die, and I will enter in that black screen loop over an over. But something happened...

[image: updater is showing me rare things]

**Why Ubuntu is recommending me AMD/ATI Drivers if I have a NVIDIA GPU?**

**Can I update the kernel or my changes will be lost?**

My laptop is a bit old, it was released in 2013 so that's why in Ubuntu 14.04, the drivers that comes in kernel `4.4.0-31-generic`, works fine¹.

*¹ I added `acpi_backlight=video` because my intel graphics have a bug in his driver, it appears on windows too, see, I have a HD Graphics 4000 so that command in `/etc/default/grub` works for manipulating the brightness*

Comment: If properly installed, the Nvidia driver will build for the new kernels. And there's no point in keeping 14.04 just because your hardware is from 2013. Newer is better, particularly for graphics.

Comment: @MichaelBay yes is properly installed, but Ubuntu is glitchy my friends call me for solving some of this problems in his laptops and  I saw like 4 times that with kernel updates, everything stops, and I fear to reinstall the OS I hate that, I like Ubunto 14 his antique software centre is nice for me.

Comment: How do you "properly" install Nvidia drivers? I have Nvidia drivers installed and there are no problems with kernel updates.

Comment: @Pilot6 In 2014 I was really annoyed for so much complicated ways to install that NVIDIA drivers but at the end... It was so freaking simple, just `ubuntu-drivers devices` read the output and put the same driver version thus the intel driver so...
`sudo apt-get install intel-microcode && nvidia-375` and that's all.

Comment: `intel-microcode` is not related to video drivers. If you installed the drivers this way, you can safely upgrade your kernel, unless DKMS is broken.

Comment: @Pilot6 dude my computer is a laptop, not a PC the GPU works with the Integrated intel graphics because the intel chip is connected to the screen not the GPU

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: it does, the intel-microcode is the graphics driver for the integrated gpu wich is required for a properly energy management with the dedicated gpu, read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU_switching in this case PRIME can change my dedicated GPU for the integrated one, it makes my computer more fresh and It will not overheat itself

Comment: `intel-microcode` is not a driver at all, and is not a graphics driver. You can search this site or wiki to read about what `intel-microcode` is.

Answer (score 3):

If Nvidia drivers have been installed from the repos or a PPA with DKMS, it will not "die" after a kernel upgrade.

AMD drivers are updated, because Ubuntu has pre-installed open source drivers for many GPUs.

I suggest upgrading all suggested packages and installing Nvidia drivers properly if there is a problem with them.

Comment: what about my grub config?I updated last month and I needed to reinstall the OS because for some reason the OS was not reading grub.cfg file, then my brightness keys was not working

Comment: dude I saw you have like 41k gold points so I'm assuming you are an expert.. can you please explain me in a more technicall way... why are you sure that DMKS will not fail?

Comment: I am not "sure" that your DKMS is not broken. Add output of `dkms status` and we can see. It always works until you break it. ))

Comment: it says this two things: `bbswitch, 0.7, 4.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed` and
`nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: It looks well. I see no reason why it won't build.

Comment: wish me luck I'll update *he cross his fingers*

Comment: well everything seems okay thanks for your time