# Ubuntu fails to boot after attempting to install Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 17.10

I attempted to install an Nvidia driver on my system using the method described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931633/how-to-install-my-nvidia-driver/931641), however when I rebooted my system the following happened during startup:

[image: Ubuntu repeatedly loads and unloads the driver]

I was able to restore normal function by booting Ubuntu in recovery mode and running apt-get purge on the Nvidia driver. But how should I properly install the Nvidia drivers, or what could have gone wrong? I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on an HP spectre x360 with a GeForce MX150 GPU.

Comment: Which Nvidia driver did you install?

Comment: I tried installing nvidia-390

Answer (score 2):

This procedure has worked for me.  A quick attempt to validate that nvidia-390 was the proper driver for your card [resulted in a finding](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/120917/en-us) that nvidia-384 might be the proper one.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390 nvidia-settings
```

Then restart your system.

If this does not work, I would repeat, replacing `nvidia-390` with `nvidia-384`.

Comment: Ubuntu listed Nvidia-390 as the recommended one, although 384 was also an option. I'll try 390 first and get back to you.

Comment: Do I reboot after completing those steps?

Comment: I tried that with both Nvidia 390 and Nvidia 384, although the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry! that has always worked for me.  There is a recent problem with gcc compiler versions breaking kernel modules, if you have a custom gcc version it could be that.  Here is one such question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010467/ubuntu-virtualbox-error/1010485#1010485 it concerns virtual box but this same problem broke my video drivers.

Comment: That's the best explanation I've heard so far

Comment: My system has gcc 7.2. How can I revert back to 4.8.4, at least for the purposes of installing the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Take a  look at this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version especially the answer from Ale.

Comment: That may not be the right gcc version for 17.10, and I don't know how to tell what the right version is.  For example, I have seen that the correct version is 5.4 for 16.04

Comment: I installed gcc and g++ version 4.8.5 and linked them so that gcc and g++ are by default 4.8.5... Should I also install an older version of the kernel, or should I go ahead and attempt to install the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Okay that... Actually worked. Or at least nothing broke when I rebooted. Thank you so much! Is there any way to verify that it installed correctly / way I could test it out?

Comment: Ubuntu told me it had issues with the package

Comment: You can do `modinfo nvidia-390 | grep vermagic` and if the result contains the word `retpoline` then the module is compiled properly.   (replace the 390 if you installed a different driver)

Comment: I purged Nvidia-390 and tried installing nvidia-384, although after rebooting I got a crash report (the same thing happened with nvidia-390)

Comment: Modinfo told me that the module wasn't fouhd. The exact error message of the crash report is;

Comment: We've now exhausted all my knowledge on video drivers and Ubuntu! I hope you have some form of a working system now.

Comment: "Sorry, a problem occurred while installing software. Package: Nvidia-384 384.1111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1" and I got a similar message with nvidia-390

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. My system "works"; it just doesn't have an Nvidia driver for the GPU

Comment: Hey Organic Marble - I just wanted to update you. I wiped Linux 17.10 and installed Linux 16.04, and everything worked.

Comment: I am glad to hear it. Thanks for closing the loop.