# Nvidia Driver 375 Install Gets Stuck on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics

Several times, I have tried installing Nvidia drivers (375) on Ubuntu 16.04.1. I have tried various methods (apt, apt-get, synaptic). I have tried some suggestions on the internet, including uninstalling the Nouveau driver first, installing before logging in, installing in safe mode, etc. But every time, the installation gets stuck at: "Building initial module for 4.4.0-59-generic". I even left the computer on for more than 24 hours, so that this step might hopefully complete, but it didn't. I tried downloading the Nvidia driver installer from the Nvidia website and following the instructions. It gets stuck at a similar step. Any suggestions?

Here is the output from synaptic:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-i386.
(Reading database ... 276721 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-i386 (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Replaced by files in installed package libc6:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32gcc1.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32gcc1_1%3a6.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32gcc1 (1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-375.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-375_375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-375 (375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcuda1-375.
Preparing to unpack .../libcuda1-375_375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcuda1-375 (375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjansson4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libjansson4_2.7-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjansson4:amd64 (2.7-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxnvctrl0.
Preparing to unpack .../libxnvctrl0_378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxnvctrl0 (378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-opencl-icd-375.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-375_375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-375 (375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bbswitch-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../bbswitch-dkms_0.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bbswitch-dkms (0.8-3ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-prime_0.8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package screen-resolution-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../screen-resolution-extra_0.17.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking screen-resolution-extra (0.17.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-settings_378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up lib32gcc1 (1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-375 (375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-375/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-375
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 124) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 133) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 124) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/'.
Loading new nvidia-375-375.26 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-59-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-59-generic
```

Comment: Ask the maintainers of the PPA, or Nvidia. The `375` is not officially supported yet.

Comment: Best to never download from nVidia site. That is not configured for Ubuntu and requires extra effort on every kernel update. If you want on need newest use ppa. But you must always totally purge old nVidia or totally uninstall the .run version before attempting to install a new version. What video card/chip do you have? http://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: Another thread on nVidia install 10XX version. http://askubuntu.com/questions/876589/ubuntu-gnome-problems-with-gtx-10xx-answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but it seems this has been answered before in another post originating by myself. But I hadn't read the last reply before:

[Kernel update gets stuck (Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel 4.4.0-22)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768892/kernel-update-gets-stuck-ubuntu-16-04-kernel-4-4-0-22)

So, it is again Eset nod32 which is at fault. After uninstalling it, restarting Ubuntu, and running "sudo dpkg --configure -a", the installation completed successfully.

BTW, I followed the instructions below to get the driver:

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that it's waiting for a password.

I entered my password a couple of time to unlock the installation process.

Source: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1036167/linux/stuck-trying-to-intall-nvidia-390-ubuntu-18-04-lts-/