# Ubuntu gnome problems with gtx 10xx + answer

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-gnome

*Today i installed a new "mobile" Ubuntu version on my new usb-stick. But I encountered several problems during the installation especially when it comes to graphics driver.*

**My system:**

```
> i7-5820K
> gtx 1070
> 16gb ddr4 ram
> asrock x99 extreme4 motherboard
> sandisk extreme 3.0 64gb usb stick (~185mb write/~200mb read)
```

**What did i do? And what happened?**

1. I downloaded the Ubuntu gnome 16.10 iso
2. I installed it on a second usb stick (with rufus.exe)
3. I booted from the usb stick
4. I installed Ubuntu gnome on the first usb stick mentioned above (note: i did not select "install 3rd party software during the installation" and "install updates during installation")
5. I booted my system from the usb stick
6. Now I wanted to install the graphics driver for my gtx-1070. So I pressed the <kbd>WIN</kbd> key and typed in "Software & Update". After lunching the application I went to the tab "Additional drivers" -> clicked on the driver for my gtx-1070 -> and then on "apply".
7. The drivers installed an I rebooted the system
8. After starting the system again it left me with an loading screen that crashed after about two minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So how did I fix my problems?**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Log into the terminal
3. Update the system `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and after that just to be sure `update-grub`
4. Reboot the system
5. Now do step 1 and 2 again
6. Now remove all not working nvidia drivers `apt-get purge nvidia-*`
7. Not lets add the repository with the drivers we need `add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
8. Now update again `apt-get update`
9. Then install the actual driver `apt-get install nvidia-375` (or instead of 375 the newest version of the driver)
10. Reboot
11. Still doesn't work?
12. Do step 1 and 2 again
13. Install lightdm instead of gdm3 by typing `apt-get install lightdm`
14. Now you should be able to choose between lightdm and gdm3. Select lightdm and press <kbd>OK</kbd>
15. Run `update-grub` and reboot again
16. The first start will take a while (in my case about three minutes)

These were the steps that I did and they worked for me.